# Normalization of an existing SQL database

Tags: sql, normalization

I have a single-table database I inherited and migrated to SQL Server, and then I normalized it by creating, linking, and filling a whole bunch of lookup-type tables that represented items in the main table.  I now want to replace those items in the original table with their foreign keys.  Am I stuck writing a bunch of queries or UDF's and then a giant INSERT statement to accomplish this, or is there a tool I can use to point at the various fields and have it handle the grunt work for me?

Answer (score 2):

Redgate [SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_refactor/index.htm) comes with a 14 day evaluation period and has a "Split Table" refactoring which sounds like it might do what you need?

The feature is described thus:

> Split Table splits a table into two
>   tables, and automatically rewrites the
>   referencing stored procedures, views,
>   and so on. **You can also use this
>   refactoring to introduce referential
>   integrity tables**. You can select this
>   feature from the context menu in
>   Management Studio’s Object Explorer.

Comment: I actually own SQL Refactor but I've only ever used it to refactor scripts I write or inherit (which it does very nicely).  Geez, I'll have to go back and look at that.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I went ahead and played with it. It does, indeed, have a function for doing something like this, but it really just creates the secondary table with SELECT DISTINCT off the primary, then assigns a foreign key constraint to the primary table's field, pointing at the new secondary table. I want to switch to integer-keyed secondary tables, replacing the field in the primary with a new integer ID field and eliminating the original varchar field. I cannot see how to make that happen with SQL Refactor. But I learned something new about a product I own, so I thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar experiences. I once inherited a fairly large database that required serious overhaul to the schema before I would look at it without scorn.

Because the upgrade was fairly significant, I designed an SSIS package to migrate data from the old schema to the new. Lookup activities were helpful to map old text values to the new keys. I kept a script of my old schema and data handy and would repeatedly restore the database in a sandbox and re-migrate until I could satisfy the powers-that-be that the migration was reliable.

I found there was only a moderate learning curve to getting started with SSIS. If the tool is available to you, I recommend giving it a try.

Comment: I've used SSIS and DTS before, I think it's a great tool.  Was hoping for something that required less grunt work, since this kind of thing must be a pretty common scenario.